# VOIP C++ Programming

Tags: c++, udp, voip, sip, rtp

I want to write a program to create VOIP application for my final year project. For this time being, I spend my time to understand how SIP works and later I need to implement it into my project. As far as i know, the protocol requirement to build this project are:

- UDP
- RTP

As for my project, it doesn't requires me to write a complex coding. I just need to provide a server that can be used as a bridge for clients to communicate. So, is there any resources that I can used for my reference to start programming my project?

Comment: Please see my answers in another question: [VoIP Programming](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43970929/7877309)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe these will be helpful to look at:

- Open source RTP library:
  [jrtplib](http://research.edm.uhasselt.be/~jori/page/index.php?n=CS.Jrtplib):
- Open source RTSP, RTP with a SIP client AFAIR:
  [liveMedia](http://live555.com/liveMedia/)
- Open source SIP library: [reSIProcate](http://www.resiprocate.org/Main_Page)

Answer (score 4):

Your best bet is pjsip.
http://www.pjsip.org/
It runs on all kinds of OSes

Comment: This is exactly a place what im looking for. Thanks alot.

Answer (score 3):

[OpenSipStack](http://www.opensourcesip.org:8080/clearspacex/index.jspa) is quite nice, it's 100% C++.

The project also contains a library for creating clients using ATL.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [OPAL](http://www.opalvoip.org/). It allows you to write applications that will support SIP, H.323 and IAX2.